# KDB: How to make evenly distributed (as possible) selections from a list?

Tags: list, random, selection, kdb

I am aware that in KDB, if you have a list like...

```
l:`apples`oranges`pears`
```

You can make N random selections like as follows:

```
9?l
```

But how do I evenly select each of the items in the list whenever possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use '#' operator to take N elements of list and do a permutation(0N?) of the result.

```
q) l:`apples`oranges`pears
q)  0N?6#l  / take and permutation
q) `pears`oranges`apples`apples`oranges`pears
```

Comment: Nice. Note that the first and subsequent permutations will always be the same (and follow the same pattern) unless the RNG seed is defined